# Trying to get primarycontactid of particular account in Dynamics 365 CRM through API and getting "Bad Request - Error in query syntax"

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-webapi

I'm sending a `GET` request to

```
{orgname}.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/accounts(accountGuid)$select=_primarycontactid_value
```

and getting an error:

> Bad Request - Error in query syntax

I'm using the query syntax I found here https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/microsoft-dynamics-crm-forum/247815/how-to-get-all-the-primary-contact-of-a-specific-account-through-api/688381

If I take off the $select parameter, I get a JObject with all of the attributes, I'm just not sure why the query syntax is wrong using that parameter. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need a **`?`** after your `(accountGuid)` - try this URL: `/api/data/v9.1/accounts(accountGuid)?$select=_primarycontact`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this below as there is a typo in your snippet. [Read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/data-platform/webapi/query-data-web-api?WT.mc_id=DX-MVP-5004422#basic-query-example)

```
{orgname}.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/accounts(accountGuid)?$select=_primarycontactid_value
```

To avoid such errors, you can always use CRM REST builder to compose and test queries.

Note: I noticed it is not your mistake, I even corrected the snippet in original forum thread from Aric. :)